# How to debug the current python test file with pytest in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, pytest

I know how to configure the **VS Code** debugger's `launch.json` to debug the current python file:

```
{ 
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"
            }
        },
}
```

But How to configure `launch.json` to debug the current python **test file** with `pytest`?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to configure? `Debug Test` button on the `Test Explorer`  can not satisfied your requirements, in the condition, you just need a basic configuration of `Python File`.

Comment: i thought if it is possible to run the debugger on something like `python file.py` it should also be possible to run it on `pytest test.py`

Comment: I am afraid it's impossible, if you want to debug, you need to start a debugger server.

Comment: so how would i debug a single python test using pytest? This must be possible, right?

Comment: Can you find the `Test Explorer`, there is `Debug Test` button next to `Test Explorer` button.

Comment: You mean `Testing` tab in the side bar? Doesn't work for my company project, some pytest discovery errors which i can't fix.

Comment: If your tests have errors, how can you test them?

Comment: the tests do not have errors. We have conftest files in non-root directories causing Test Explorer / Discovery to fail. But it should still be possible to debug single test files with this project setup as it is no problem for pycharm.

Answer (score 16):

This is what works for me in the context of Django and Pytest:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Debug test file",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "module": "pytest",
  "args": [
    "${file}"
  ],
  "django": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below configuration in your launch.json file, it should work.

```
 "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Pytest",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "pytest",
      "args": [
        "${file}"
      ],
        },
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{ 
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args" : ["-s", "-q", "-m <id inpytest.ini>", "-myArgu1=xxx"]            
            
        }]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).